# Paypal payment_gross is empty

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am working with with paypal sandbox.

According with [that article](http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=PayPal) after IPN verification i need to check `payment_gross` field but in my case it is empty.

Also i have fields `mc_gross` and `mc_gross_1` which is contains paid amount so should i check `mc_gross` insteard? any thoughts why `payment_gross` is empty?

Comment: Looks like payment_gross has been abandoned by PayPal and replaced by mc_gross. Same thing happened to me but payment_gross is no longer documented or shown on the Sandbox IPN test page.

Comment: Also helpful: [PayPal IPN Example: Completed, Reversed, Canceled_Reversed and Refunded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31451449/1066234)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why `payment_gross` is empty (or whether or not it should be) but I've always used `mc_gross` to check the payment amount and I've never had any problems. In fact if memory serves I originally copied that from a PHP code sample from the Paypal developer documents.

Comment: just googled that reference https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_TransactionSearch it is saying that `payment_gross` only for USD currency.

Answer (score 11):

1. payment_gross: Will be empty for non-USDpayments. This is a legacy fieldreplaced by
2. mc_gross: If this amount is negative, it signifies a refund or reversal, and either of those payment statuses can be for the full or partial amount of the original transaction.

Make sense?